# Memory size of Java 32-bit system int[] arrays

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, int

In Java, on a 32 bit OS, I store `5736 int[]` arrays containing `54759118` ints. If each `int` primitive takes `4` bytes, then I will get minimum `54759118 * 4 = 219036472 bytes ~ 220 megabytes`. Since I have `5736` references to `int[]` objects, what will be an overhead of storing those references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `32-bit` pointer in Java allocates ~4 bytes. Hence, it will be `5736 * 4 = 22944 bytes`

Comment: There are only `5736` references

Comment: @Heuster ups :)) Thank you very much, its my inattention.

Comment: Thank you, so this will be an overhead size, `23 megabytes`? Is something spent on storing say length of array, or only ints as contents and array references are stored?

Comment: @SophieSperner 4 bytes per an array reference. It doesn't depend on array's length. And it is only `22 kilobytes`, not megabytes :)

Comment: Just a comment aside: by the link at the end they say that `int[1024]` takes `4112` bytes. If you use our logic: `1024 * 4 + 4 (ref) = 4100 < 4112` consequently `12` bytes are stored for something else. Link: http://vanillajava.blogspot.ie/2011/07/java-how-much-memory-do-different.html